# Bitcoin wallet security

Tags: wallet

If I use a Bitcoin wallet from say Bitcoin.com and Bitcoin.com folds, will I still be able to download the software and input my pass phrase to get my bitcoin back?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help by marking answers as accepted once your question is answered so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to save the seed phrase mnemonic (likely 12-24 words long) that the wallet gives you when you first start it up. **Doing so is very important!**

If Bitcoin.com disappears tomorrow, you'll be able to input that seed phrase into any other compatible piece software. Many wallets use the same key derivation scheme.

Comment: To add to the above you can also find the option to backup the seed mnemonic via settings > bitcoin wallet > personal wallet > backup